# Can I use NULL as substitution for the value of 0?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, null, language-lawyer

Am I allowed to use the `NULL` pointer as replacement for the value of `0`?

Or is there anything wrong about that doing?

---

Like, for example:

```
int i = NULL;
```

as replacement for:

```
int i = 0;
```

---

As experiment I compiled the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = NULL;
    printf("%d",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Indeed it gives me this warning, which is completely correct on its own:

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

but the result is still equivalent.

---

- Am I crossing into "Undefined Behavior" with this?
- Is it permissible to utilize `NULL` in this way?
- Is there anything wrong with using `NULL` as a numerical value in arithmetical expressions?
- And what is the result and behavior in C++ for this case?

---

I have read the answers of [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0) about what the difference between `NULL`, `\0` and `0` is, but I did not get the concise information from there, if it is quite permissible and also right to use `NULL` as value to operate with in assignments and other arithmetical operations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204757/discussion-on-question-by-roberts-reinstate-monica-can-i-use-null-as-substitut).

Comment: It would really be better to ask two separate questions, one for C and one for C++.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> Am I allowed to use the NULL pointer as replacement for the value of 0?

**No**, it is not safe to do so.  `NULL` is a null-pointer constant, which *could* have type `int`, but which more typically has type `void *` (in C), or otherwise is not directly assignable to an `int` (in C++ >= 11).  Both languages allow pointers to be converted to integers, but they do not provide for such conversions to be performed implicitly (though some compilers provide that as an extension).  Moreover, although it is common for converting a null pointer to an integer to yield the value 0, the standard does not guarantee that.  If you want a constant with type `int` and value 0 then spell it `0`.

> - Am I might crossing into Undefined Behavior with this?

Yes, on any implementation where `NULL` expands to a value with type `void *` or any other not directly assignable to `int`.  The standard does not define the behavior of your assignment on such an implementation, ergo its behavior is undefined.

> - is it permissible to operate with the NULL in that way?

It is poor style, and it will break on some systems and under some circumstances.  Inasmuch as you appear to be using GCC, it would break in your own example if you compiled with the `-Werror` option.

> - Is there anything wrong about to use NULL as numerical value in arithmetical expressions?

Yes.  It is not guaranteed to have a numerical value at all.  If you mean 0 then write 0, which is not only well defined, but shorter and clearer.

> - And how is the result in C++ to that case?

The C++ language is stricter about conversions than is C and has different rules for `NULL`, but there, too, implementations may provide extensions.  Again, if you mean 0 then that's what you should write.

Comment: You should point out that "which more typically has type `void *`" is only true of C.  `void *` is not a legal type for C++ (because you can't assign `void*` to any other pointer type).  In C++89 and C++03, in fact `NULL` *must* be of type `int`, but in later versions it can be (and usually is) `nullptr_t`.

Comment: You are also wrong the converting `void*` to `int` is undefined behaviour.  It is not; it is implementation specified behaviour.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, In those contexts where C specifies that a pointer is converted to an integer, the result of the conversion is indeed implementation-specified, but that's not what I'm talking about. It is assignment of a pointer to an lvalue of integer type (without explicitly converting via a cast) that has undefined behavior.  The language does not define an automatic conversion there.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, I have edited to be more inclusive of C++ considerations.  In any event, the central theme applies equally to both languages: if you want an integer 0 then write it explicitly as an integer constant of appropriate type.

Answer (score 32):

`NULL` is some null pointer constant. In C it could be an integer constant expression with value `0` or such an expression cast to `void*`, with the latter more likely. Which means you *can't* assume to use `NULL` interchangeably with zero. For instance, in this code sample

```
char const* foo = "bar"; 
foo + 0;
```

Replacing `0` with `NULL` is not guaranteed to be a valid C program, because addition between two pointers (let alone of different pointer types) is not defined. It will cause a diagnostic to be issued due to a constraint violation. [The operands for addition will not be valid](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p2).

---

As for C++, things are somewhat different. Lack of an implicit conversion from `void*` to other object types meant that `NULL` was historically defined as `0` in C++ code. In C++03, you could probably get away with it. But since C++11 it can legally [be defined as the `nullptr` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200674/is-null-defined-as-nullptr-in-c11). Now again producing an error, since `std::nullptr_t` may not be added to pointer types.

If `NULL` is defined as `nullptr` then even your experiment becomes invalid. There is no conversion from `std::nullptr_t` to an integer. That is why it is considered a safer null pointer constant.

Comment: For completeness, 0L is also a null pointer constant and could be used as `NULL` in both languages.

Comment: @eerorika - I think we can do one better. Copied the full definition into the answer.

Comment: @eerorika: Is 0L ALWAYS a NULL pointer?  I'm recalling segmented architectures like the 80286, where a far pointer was two separate registers, and IIRC you could validly set the offset to zero.  (Quite apart from the fact that IMHO it's always better to say exactly what you mean in code.  If you're assigning to a numeric variable, use 0 or 0.0; if to a pointer, then NULL.)

Comment: @jamesqf The standard says that integer constant with value 0 is a null pointer constant. Therefore 0L is a null pointer constant.

Comment: @eerorika: Just what the world needs, standards that ignore reality :-)  'Cause if I'm remembering my 80286 assembly correctly, you can't even assign a far pointer as a single operation,  so the compiler writers would have to special-case it.

Comment: @jamesqf Per [the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html), re: making `0` a null pointer constant: "evidently as a sop to all the extant poorly-written C code which made incorrect assumptions"

Comment: @jamesqf, that any and every integer constant with value 0 is a null-pointer constant (in C) has nothing to do with hardware pointer implementations.  Note also that standard C does not recognize a distinction between near and far pointers in any case, but does support pointer-to-pointer assignments.  It also supports (some) pointer comparisons, which present interesting issues for segmented addressing formats such as the 286's.

Comment: @jamesqf: it ignores reality in a way that doesn't matter. Note that it's only ICEs with value 0 that are guaranteed to work, not just any old integer expression that happens to have value 0. So yes, the compiler can special-case it if needed, and substitute in whatever the actual null-pointer-pattern is, because it's known at compile time whether or not an integer expression is an ICE or not.

Comment: Then, `void *foo = 0L;` will not necessarily have the same result as `long get_null() { return 0;}` ... `void *foo = get_null();`. I don't believe this poses any problem for compiler-writers, just for the misguided author of `get_null`. The standard in effect says that assigning an ICE with value 0 to a pointer has a special meaning, which is to set the pointer to null. Once you know the null pointer representation this is not hard to implement on any architecture :-)

Comment: Or, to put in another way, treating 0-valued ICEs as a special case was, prior to C++11, considered better than having a null pointer type. I suspect (but I'm not sure) that this is because it was actually considered *easier* for compiler-writers to implement the special case than the special type!

Answer (score 22):

> Am I allowed to use the NULL pointer as a replacement for the value of 0?
>
> ```
> int i = NULL;
> ```

The rules vary between languages and their versions. In some cases you *can* and in others, you can't. Regardless, you **shouldn't**. If you're lucky, your compiler will warn when you attempt it or even better, fail to compile.

In C++, prior to C++11 (quote from C++03):

> [lib.support.types]
>
> NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard.

It makes little sense to use a null pointer constant as an integer. However...

> [conv.ptr]
>
> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero.

So, it would technically work even if it's nonsensical. Due to this technicality, you may encounter poorly written programs that abuse `NULL`.

Since C++11 (quote from latest draft):

> [conv.ptr]
>
> A null pointer constant is an integer literal ([lex.icon]) with value zero **or a prvalue of type std​::​nullptr_­t**.

A `std​::​nullptr_­t` is not convertible to an integer, so using `NULL` as integer would work only conditionally, depending on choices made by the language implementation.

P.S. `nullptr` is a prvalue of type `std​::​nullptr_­t`. Unless you need your program to compile in pre-C++11, you should always use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

---

C is a bit different (quotes from C11 draft N1548):

> 6.3.2.3 Language / Conversions / Other operands / Pointers
>
> 3 An integer constant expression with the value  0,  **or such an expression cast to type `void *`**, is called a null pointer constant. ...

So, the case is similar to post C++11 i.e. the abuse of `NULL` works conditionally depending on choices made by the language implementation.

Answer (score 10):

**Yes**, though depending on the implementation you *may* need a cast. But yes, it is 100% legitimate, otherwise.

Although it is really, really, really bad style (needless to say?).

`NULL` is, or was, *actually* not C++, it is C. The standard *does* however, like for many C legacies, have two clauses ([diff.null] and [support.types.nullptr]) which technically make `NULL` C++. It is an **implementation-defined null-pointer constant**. Therefore, even if it's bad style, it's technically as C++ as it can be.
As pointed out in the [footnote](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/support.types.nullptr#footnote-184), possible implementations could be `0` or `0L`, but **not**  `(void*)0`.

`NULL` could, of course (the standard doesn't explicitly say so, but it's pretty much the only choice remaining after `0` or `0L`) be `nullptr`. That's almost never the case, but it is a legal possibility.

The warning that the compiler showed to you demonstrates that the compiler is in fact not compliant (unless you compiled in C mode). Because, well, according to the warning, it *did convert* a null pointer (not `nullptr` which would be of `nullptr_t`, which would be distinct), so apparently the definition of `NULL` is indeed `(void*)0`, which it may not be.

Either way, you have two possible legitimate (i.e. compiler not broken) cases. Either (the realistic case), `NULL` is something like `0` or `0L`, then you have *"zero or one"* conversions to integer, and you are good to go.

Or `NULL` is indeed `nullptr`. In that case you have a distinct value that has guarantees about comparison as well as clearly-defined conversions **from** integers, but unluckily not **to** integers. It does, however, have a clearly-defined conversion to `bool` (resulting in `false`), and `bool` has a clearly-defined conversion to integer (resulting in `0`).

Unluckily, that's *two* conversions, so it's not within *"zero or one"* as pointed out in [conv]. Thus, if your implementation defines `NULL` as `nullptr`, then you will have to add an explicit cast for your code to be correct.

Answer (score 6):

From the C faq:

> **Q:** If NULL and 0 are equivalent as null pointer constants, which should I use?
>
> **A:** It is only in pointer contexts that `NULL` and `0` are equivalent. `NULL` should *not* be used when another kind of 0 is required, even though it might work, because doing so sends the wrong stylistic message. (Furthermore, ANSI allows the definition of NULL to be `((void *)0)`, which will not work at all in non-pointer contexts.) In particular, do not use `NULL` when the ASCII null character (NUL) is desired. Provide your own definition
>
> http://c-faq.com/null/nullor0.html

Answer (score 5):

*Disclaimer: I don't know C++. My answer is not meant to be applied in the context of C++*

`'\0'` is an `int` with value zero, just 100% exactly like `0`.

```
for (int k = 10; k > '\0'; k--) /* void */;
for (int k = 10; k > 0; k--) /* void */;
```

**In the context of pointers**, `0` and `NULL` are 100% equivalent:

```
if (ptr) /* ... */;
if (ptr != NULL) /* ... */;
if (ptr != '\0') /* ... */;
if (ptr != 0) /* ... */;
```

are all 100% equivalent.

---

Note about `ptr + NULL`

The context of `ptr + NULL` is **not** that of pointers. There is no definition for the addition of pointers in the C language; pointers and integers can be added (or subtracted). In `ptr + NULL` if either `ptr` or `NULL` is a pointer, the other **must be** an integer, so `ptr + NULL` is effectively `(int)ptr + NULL` or `ptr + (int)NULL` and depending on the definitions of `ptr` and `NULL` several behaviours can be expected: it all working, warning for conversion between pointer and integer, failure to compile, ...

Comment: I've seen `#define NULL (void *)0` before. Are you sure NULL and plain 0 are 100% equivalent?

Comment: In the context of pointer, yes ... condition emphasized in my answer, thank you

Comment: @phuclv: I have absolutely no idea about C++. My answer (except the bit between parenthesis) is about C

Comment: @phuclv `ptr + NULL` is not using `NULL` in the context of pointers

Comment: "0 and NULL are 100% equivalent" - No they are not. NULL is often (but not always) defined as `((void*)0)` - which is *not* the same as `0`. And certainly not the same as `nullptr`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: **in the context of pointers** they are 100% equivalent. I have no idea what `nullptr` is, but `((void*)0)` and `0` (or `'\0'`) are equivalent in the context of pointers ... `if (ptr == '\0' /* or equivalent 0, NULL */)`

Answer (score 5):

No, not anymore preferred to use `NULL`(old way of pointer initilization).

Since C++11:

The keyword `nullptr` denotes the pointer literal. It is a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. There exist implicit conversions from `nullptr` to null pointer value of any pointer type and any pointer to member type. Similar conversions exist for any null pointer constant, which includes values of type `std::nullptr_t` as well as the macro `NULL`.

[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr](http://Reference%20for%20documetation)

Actually, **std::nullptr_t** is the type of the null pointer literal, `nullptr`. It is a distinct type that is not itself a pointer type or a pointer to member type.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

void f(int* pi)
{
   std::cout << "Pointer to integer overload\n";
}

void f(double* pd)
{
   std::cout << "Pointer to double overload\n";
}

void f(std::nullptr_t nullp)
{
   std::cout << "null pointer overload\n";
}

int main()
{
    int* pi; double* pd;

    f(pi);
    f(pd);
    f(nullptr);  // would be ambiguous without void f(nullptr_t)
    // f(0);  // ambiguous call: all three functions are candidates
    // f(NULL); // ambiguous if NULL is an integral null pointer constant 
                // (as is the case in most implementations)
}
```

Output:

```
Pointer to integer overload
Pointer to double overload
null pointer overload
```

Comment: The question is about assigning NULL to 0 for integers. In this sense, nothing changes with nullptr instead of NULL.

Comment: By the way, C++ do not have the NULL concept after C++11. Author might be confused about using the constexpr or define old way initialization. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization