# Is it OK/valid to intialize an array of integer type inside of a structure to NULL?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, null

Assume I have this structure:

```c
typedef struct foo
{
bool bar[4];
}foo;
```

and then I want to create an array of that structure:

```c
foo foo_arr[] = {
{{true, true, false, true}}, 
{{false, true, false, true}}, 
{NULL}
};
```

Is the Initialization of the struct at `foo_arr[2]` valid? And if not, what is the correct way to point such array to `NULL`?

- Requirement: The structure needs to be allocated on the stack.

Comment: What is the size of the array? if you want a flexibe array member there must be at least one member before `arr` and you can not use more than one element in such case

Comment: why do you even need `NULL` in the first place? how about sticking to 2 elements only?

Comment: @Infinity this is just a demo. in my real code the struct has much more fields than just the array, but just the array should be NULL.

Comment: @DavidRanieri what do you mean? should I post the full struct for context?

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the behaviour, you need to define the size of the array, do you mean `bool bar[4];`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri yes I forgot to add it, thanks!

Comment: Arrays don't "point to" anything, and the use of `NULL` here has nothing to do with pointers (and you should probably use something else, as a style matter). You may benefit from reading through http://c-faq.com/aryptr/.

Comment: @Basile but this is ansi C

Comment: Ansi C is an obsolete standard. It is difficult to find a compiler compatible with ANSI C. C11 is upward compatible. Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and see [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Consider using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/). Provide some [mre] in your next question, yours is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*Is it OK to make a global stack allocated array point to `NULL`?*"
>
> "*Is the init(ialization) of the struct at `foo_arr[2]` valid?*"

No, it is not OK and not valid. At least not in the way you did (C syntax violation with `{NULL}` - it needs to be `{{NULL}}` to get compiled).

```
typedef struct foo
{
   bool bar[4];
} foo;

foo foo_arr[] = {
    {{true, true, false, true}}, 
    {{false, true, false, true}}, 
    {{NULL}}
};
```

Indeed, under some requirements this would initialize all elements of `bar` to `0`, but lets start at the beginning.

Why would you want to use `NULL`? `NULL` is used to compare and set *pointers*, not data objects. `bar` is not an array of pointers.

I indeed had a similar question myself, a few months ago:

- [Can I use NULL as substitution for the value of 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59437282/12139179)

It is implementation-defined whether it is valid to use `NULL` to initialize data objects to `0`, since the `NULL` macro either expands to `0` or `(void*) 0`. If it is the latter, the implementation needs to specify what happens if you assign a pointer to `void` to an integer type.

> "*Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.*"
>
> Source: C18, 6.3.2.3/6

So if either,

1. `NULL` expands to `0` on your specific implementation, or
2. The implementation specifies conversions from pointers to integers (the conversion from `(void*) 0` to an data object),

this would indeed initialize all elements of `bar` in the third structure to `0`, because of following:

In the first place, `{{NULL}}` set the first `bool` object in the array `bar` in the third structure of the array `foo_arr` to `0`.

Implicitly it will also initialize all following three `bool` object to `0`, because:

> "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than thereare elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."
>
> Source: C18, 6.7.9/20

This means if you intialize the first `bool` object it will automatically initialize all others.

---

> "*If not, what is the correct way to point such array to `NULL`?*"

As said above, not to `NULL`, to `0` or `false`. The array (elements) do not *point* to anywhere. They are not pointers! As indicated above you can just use `{{0}}` or `{{false}}`:

```
typedef struct foo
{
   bool bar[4];
} foo;

foo foo_arr[] = {
    {{true, true, false, true}}, 
    {{false, true, false, true}}, 
    {{0}};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In the same way you can not use:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, NULL};
```

you can not set an element expecting a `foo` type to `NULL`, to do that you need to use an array of pointers to `foo`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct foo
{
    bool bar[4];
} foo;

int main(void)
{
    foo foo_arr[] = {{{true, true, false, true}}, {{false, true, false, true}}};
    foo *foo_ap[] = {&foo_arr[0], &foo_arr[1], NULL};

    for (int i = 0; foo_ap[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        foo *foo_ptr = foo_ap[i];

        printf("%d %d %d %d\n",
                foo_ptr->bar[0],
                foo_ptr->bar[1],
                foo_ptr->bar[2],
                foo_ptr->bar[3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 0 1
0 1 0 1
```